# Rails - CanCanCan, Rolify, Define - Defining Abilities for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan, rolify

I am using Devise for Authentication & CanCanCan / Rolify for Authorisation.

I’m wanting to restrict each model’s record, to the user who created it, via the various associations.

I.e. /sales/1 should only be viewable by the User who belongs_to the organisation that has the sale.

```
User
   has_many :organisations

Organisation
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :sales

Sale
   belongs_to :organisation
   has_many :payments

Payment
   belongs_to :sale
```

Restricting the Organisation to the User who belongs to it is straight forward:

```
class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.has_role? :admin
        can :manage, :all
      elsif user.has_role? :standard
        can [:create, :read, :update, :destroy], Organisation, :user_id => user.id
      end
   end
end
```

How can I achieve the same thing for an associated Sale and subsequently an associated Payment?

```
can [:manage], Sale, ?

can [:manage], Payment, ?
```

Note: Rails 5.0.0.1, Ruby 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add association in payment.rb

```
 belongs_to :sale
 has_one :organisation, through: :sale
```

and then you can add in ability.rb

```
 can :manage, Sale, :organisation => { :user_id => user.id }
 can :manage, Payment, :organisation => { :user_id => user.id }
```